# Find ButtonField in Gridview's Row DataBound Event

Tags: c#, vb.net, gridview

Here is my Inline Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdVacation" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>

   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No">
               <HeaderTemplate>
               Sno</HeaderTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
               <%#Container.DataItemIndex + 1%>
               </ItemTemplateField>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Badge No" DataField="EmpBadge" />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Vacation Date" DataField="LastVacDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Vacation Expiry Date" DataField="VacValidity" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Vacation Start Date" DataField="VacStartDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Vacation End Date" DataField="VacEndDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="13 Salary Request" DataField="E13SalRequest" />
   <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" CommandName="select" HeaderText="Edit" ImageUrl="~/images/Edit.png"></asp:ButtonField>

</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am about to Change the Image URL of the ButtonFiled on some condition in GridView **RowDataBound** event.

The Code what i have tried so far,

```
   Protected Sub GrdVacation_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GrdVacation.RowDataBound

    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
    Dim NM = CType(e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(7), ImageButton)

     if(true) Then
        NM.ImageURL="somepath"
     End If
```

I am getting exception as *Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.*
Please suggest me what went wrong.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a `TemplateField` with an  `ImageButton`? Then you can use `e.Row.FindControl("ID")` to get the reference which is much more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I did so, But it could not fire the GridView_SelectedIndexChanged event.

Comment: You have to set the `ImageButton`'s `CommandName` to `Select` to trigger that event. You should also ensure that the `GridView` is not databound on postbacks, therefore use `if(!IsPostBack) DataBindGrid();`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I tried that too, But it did not fire GridView_SelectedIndexChanged event

Comment: @Thirisangu: have you really ensured that the GridView gets databound only `If Not Page.IsPostBack`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes., i have done so.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Dim NM = CType(e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(7), ImageButton)
```

to

```
Dim NM = CType(e.Row.Cells(7).Controls(0), ImageButton)
```

Like this:

```
Protected Sub GrdVacation_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GrdVacation.RowDataBound

    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
    //// Dim NM = CType(e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(7), ImageButton)
    Dim NM = CType(e.Row.Cells(7).Controls(0), ImageButton)


     if(true) Then
        NM.ImageURL="somepath"
     End If
```

Comment: actually you were referring `cells(0)` while your image button control is in `cells(7)`. You have a collection of Cells and not the control. So control is positioned at `0` th index of Cell 7.